# Quero passar variáveis JS para um arquivo EJS, como posso fazer isso?

Tags: node.js, ejs

venho tentando fazer um chat, e o username do cliente está na `req.session` do cliente. E para aparecer o noe dos usuário no canto da tela, preciso pegar essa variável do usuário, para isso, na index.js eu coloquei isso:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    if(req.session.userName == ''){
        res.render('redirectLogin.ejs')
    }
    if(!req.session.userName){
        req.session.userName == ''
        res.render('redirectLogin.ejs')
    }else{
        res.render('index.ejs', { userName: req.session.userName });
    }
});
```

e na tal index.ejs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var name = <%=userName%>

        var socket = io();

        var messages = document.getElementById('messages');
        var usersUl = document.getElementById('users');
        var usersTitle = document.getElementById('usersH1');
        var form = document.getElementById('form');
```

E está dando erro nessa parte: `var name = <%=userName%>`, dizendo que não posso colocar os `<%= %>`

Comment: Tente com o uso de aspas: `var name = "<%=userName%>"`

Comment: achei q seria mais difícil, vlw deu certo

Comment: agora eu quero fazer o contrário, quero passar uma variável da index.ejs, para o servidor, como faço isso???????????

Comment: Não há como fazer isso diretamente . Vai ter que usar o JS e fazer uma chamada HTTP (via _axios_ ou _fetch_) para o servidor receber este valor.

Comment: é que eu coloquei sistema de points por mensagem, dai eu queria que os pontos ficassem salvos no ```req.session```

Comment: ah, já consegui fazer isso com socket.io